# Clone Azure Linux VM

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I need to clone a Linux VM currently in production in Azure (it is a database server that is being used in a live environment).

I did a little research and it seems like you need to run a deprovisioning command to essentially remove things like SSH keys and other stuff which looks kinda scary to me; I saw language in other articles describing things like "after you backup, your existing VM is deleted, etc" and other things that I'm not sure about but don't seem like what I want.

Is there a safe way to just clone a box and bring it back up? In AWS it's very easy you just create an image, the box goes down for a min, and then you create a new instance from there.

Could someone just give me the steps in Azure? Do I want to click 'capture' at the top for the linux instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a safe way to just clone a box and bring it back up?

According to your description, I think you are looking for **Recovery services vault**.

We can use recovery services vault to backup Azure VM and restore Azure VM, more information about step by step to setup recovery services vault, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms).

> Do I want to click 'capture' at the top for the linux instance?

Capture used for create VM image, after captured, we can use that image to create multiple VMs. Not a backup.

> it seems like you need to run a deprovisioning command to essentially
>   remove things like SSH keys and other stuff which looks kinda scary to
>   me; I saw language in other articles describing things like "after you
>   backup, your existing VM is deleted, etc"

You are right, that is prepare a new image, not a backup.

If you just want to backup that VM once, maybe we can copy that VHD to storage account with different name.

Comment: Thanks for responding and confirming my suspicions; Can the Recovery Services Vault approach also create a new VM for me?

Comment: @NullHypothesis Yes, we can use recovery service vault to create a new VM.  we can create a new VM from a restore point via Azure portal, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms#create-a-new-vm-from-a-restore-point).

Comment: Thank you and this will leave the original VM intact and not destroy it and leave it running, right?

Comment: @NullHypothesis Right, that will create a new VM with the different virtual network.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help - this is what I needed and I appreciate you taking the time out to help me!

Comment: @NullHypothesis When we chose restore that VM, we can select resource group, subnet, virtual network, but it will create a new network cards.